# Disabling automatic selection of the first item in a PrimeNG popup menu

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, primeng

I’m using the p-menu component from PrimeNG in popup mode ([popup]="true"), and I’ve encountered an undesired behavior: the first item in the menu is automatically selected and turns gray`,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCB75.png)

```
<p-menu #menu [popup]="true" [model]="items">
    <ng-template pTemplate="item" let-item>
        <a class="p-menuitem-link flex justify-content-between align-items-center" 
            *ngIf="item.icon=='delete', else other">
            <div class="tw-flex tw-items-center tw-space-x-2" [ngStyle]="{'color': item.icon === 'delete' ? 'red' : 'inherit'}" (click)="confirm1($event)"> 
                <span class="material-icons-round">{{ item.icon }}</span>
                <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
            </div>
        </a>
        <ng-template #other>
            <a class="p-menuitem-link flex justify-content-between align-items-center"> 
                <div class="tw-flex tw-items-center tw-space-x-2"> 
                    <span class="material-icons-round">{{ item.icon }}</span>
                    <span>{{ item.label }}</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        </ng-template>
    </ng-template>
</p-menu>
```

I’ve tried several solutions, including adding a hidden item at the beginning of the menu and modifying the CSS, but none have worked. Does anyone know how I can disable the automatic selection of the first item in a p-menu in popup mode?

Of course, here’s how you could answer these questions in English for your Stack Overflow post:

What did you try?

I’m using the p-menu component from PrimeNG in popup mode ([popup]="true"). I’ve tried several solutions to disable the automatic selection of the first item in the menu, including adding a hidden item at the beginning of the menu and modifying the CSS.

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on Stackblitz?

Answer (score 0):

To disable the automatic selection of the first item in a PrimeNG popup menu, you can explore the following areas:

• PrimeNG p-menu configuration
• CSS customization